# How to reset User properties / Script properties, GAS data storage

Tags: google-apps-script

I renamed through the interface on UserProperty to blank (a space). Since then I get a "Data Storage Error" when trying to read or write a User or Script property.

e.g.

```
function test() {
  UserProperties.getProperty("foo");
}
```

I even can't access anymore the list of properties through the user interface

Does someone have an idea on how I could even reset the whole data storage ?

Comment: This problem is already submitted to the [GAS Issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1454). Recently I also caught this issue.

Answer (score 0):

i had to copy the code, delete the project entirely, create a new project and paste my code back in.

Comment: This probably works for a Script Property, but not for a User Property I guess.

Comment: @user1498332: Seems for the user properties, it will a solution to delete and create a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Use: **`userProperties.deleteAllProperties()`**

```
try {
  // Get user properties in the current script.
  const userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  // Delete all user properties in the current script.
  userProperties.deleteAllProperties();
} catch (err) {
  // TODO (developer) - Handle exception
  console.log('Failed with error %s', err.message);
}
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#deleting_data