# Error Data Storage

Tags: google-apps-script

In all my scripts, when I want to check the script properties, I get this error:

> Error Data Storage

and now I cannot access the Project Properties window at all. What can be the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please post bug reports to the issue tracker, not stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You are not alone. The problem is an empty property name. This issue is reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308215/how-to-reset-user-properties-script-properties-gas-data-storage) (with a possible workaround) and on the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1519).